# Live server error: InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137: View [welcome] not found

Tags: php, linux, laravel, model-view-controller

I have developed a Laravel application which works well on a local machine.
Local is windows and live server is linux.

On live it gives error like

> InvalidArgumentException in FileViewFinder.php line 137:
>   View [welcome] not found.

in FileViewFinder it still takes path of Xampp/htdocc/xxx

> FileViewFinder->findInPaths('welcome', array('C:\xampp\htdocs\CRM\resources\views', '/mnt/data/vhosts/casite-673772.cloudaccess.net/httpdocs/CRM/app\Modules\User\Views')) in FileViewFinder.php line 79

Comment: does the 'welcome' view exist and is accessible to the webserver?

Comment: Yes it exists and its accessible @lagbox

Comment: what is the filename of this welcome view?

Comment: its welcome.blade.php @lagbox and it works well in local windows server.

Comment: Try `php artisan cache:clear` on the Linux box.

Comment: I dont have that machines access i have uploaded through FileZilla @MarkDavidson ... How to run command?

Comment: Try deleting `storage/framework/cache/` on the Linux box.

Comment: Still same error @MarkDavidson

Comment: @MarkDavidson thanks i have done it through route like     Route::get('/cmd', function () {
  chdir('../');
  $dir =  getcwd();
  print_r($dir);
  $cmd = shell_exec ('php artisan cache:clear');
  return $cmd;
 });

Answer (score 1):

@thanks i have done it through route like

```
Route::get('/cmd', function () {
    chdir('../');
    $dir =  getcwd();
    print_r($dir);
    $cmd = shell_exec ('php artisan cache:clear');
    return $cmd;
});
```